# Proving a sequence is bounded from below

Tags: calculus

Let $$a_1=3\quad , \quad a_{n+1}=\frac{3a_n}{4}+\frac{1}{a_n}$$
Show that $a_n$ converges.

I know that I need to prove that $a_n$ is monotonic and bounded.

I've assumed that the limit exists, made the calculation and get that $L=2$, hence claiming two claims:

1. $a_n\ge 2$ (I know that 0 is a simpler bound)
2. $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing.

Now, if I can prove the first claim. then I can write $$a_{n+1}=\frac{3a_n}{4}+\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{3a_n}{4}+\frac{a_n}{a_n^2}\le \frac{3a_n}{4}+\frac{a_n}{4}=a_n$$ which proves the second claim.

My only problem is proving the first one. If it is not the right direction, please hint me.

Comment: I think it oscillates above and below 2, but I might be wrong

Comment: @mathworker21, it does not.

Comment: 1. You write "I've assumed that the limit exists, made the calculation and get that L=2". That is wrong. Show  us your calculation.

Comment: 2. Why do you think you  have to use monotonicity? There are convergent sequences that are no monotone.

Comment: @miracle173, let $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$, then applying limit to both sides gives the equation $$L=\frac{3L}{4}+\frac{1}{L}\iff L^2=4\iff L=\pm 2$$ and clearly $a_n>0$, thus $L=2$. Also, I have not written the question as it given - it asks "show that the sequence is monotonic and bounded, thus converges".

Comment: @y12 thanks, your calculation is correct. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show boundedness from below, you may use AM-GM:
$$\frac{3a_n}{4}+\frac{1}{a_n}\geq 2 \sqrt{\frac{3a_n}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{a_n}}= \sqrt{3}$$
For convergence you may proceed as follows:

- $f(x) = \frac{3x}{4} + \frac{1}{x}$ has a fixpoint for $x^{\star} = 2$
- $f'(x) = \frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{x^2}$
- A quick calculation shows that $|f'(x)| < 1$ for $x > \frac{2}{\sqrt{7}} \Rightarrow |f'(x)| \leq \color{blue}{q} < 1$ for $x \geq \sqrt{3}$

So, for any starting value $a_0 > 0$ you get 
$$|2-a_{n+1}| = |f'(\xi_n)||2-a_n| < \color{blue}{q} |2-a_n| < \color{blue}{q^n}|2-a_1|\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

**Edit after comment:**

Specifically for your question concerning $a_n \geq 2$:
$$ \color{blue}{a_{n+1}-2} = \frac{3a_n}{4}+\frac{1}{a_n} - \left(\frac{3\cdot 2}{4}+\frac{1}{2} \right)= \frac{3}{4}\left( a_n - 2 \right) - \frac{a_n - 2}{2a_n}$$
$$ = \left(\frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{2a_n} \right)(a_n -2) \stackrel{\color{blue}{a_n \geq 2}}{\geq} \frac{1}{2}(a_n -2) \color{blue}{\geq 0}$$

Comment: "show that $a_n$ converges"

Comment: A simpler lower bound for $a_n$ is $0$, but from that I cannot show that $a_n$ decreases...

Comment: @y12: Yes. But the lower bound $\sqrt{3}$ is very useful for showing that the iteration converges for any starting value $a_0 > 0$ to the positive fixpoint of $f$, because $a_1 \geq \sqrt{3} > \frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}$.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use functions...

Comment: @y12: I added something concerning your specific question.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality $ x \geq 2$ implies $\frac {3x} 4+\frac 1 x \geq 2$ because$\frac {3x} 4+\frac 1 x$ is increasing on $x >\frac 2 {\sqrt3}$ (and $\frac {3\times 2} 4+\frac 1 2 =2$). This gives (by induction) $a_n \geq 2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Kavi Rama.You show (nicely) that for $x\ge 2$ your function is increasing.But $a_n$ is decreasing . Could go below $2$? By AM-GM $\ge √3$.Your thoughts , thanks, Peter http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%2B1%29%3D%283%2F4%29f%28n%29%2B1%2Ff%28n%29%2C+f%281%29%3D3

Comment: No, it cannot. $a_n \geq 2$ implies $\frac {3a_n} 4+\frac 1 {a_n} \geq \frac {(3)(2)} 4+\frac 1 2 =2$. Use induction to conclude that every $a_n \geq 2$.

Comment: Kavi Rama.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=2+d_n .$ Then $$d_{n+1}=3(2+d_n)/4+ 1/(2+d_n)-2.$$ Use some elementary algebra on this to show that $d_n>0\implies d_n>d_{n+1}>0.$

So by induction on $n,$ if $0<a_1-2=d_1$ then $a_n$ decreases strictly to a limit $L\geq 2.$

Comment: You should get (assuming $d_n\ne -2$) that $d_{n+1}=d_n(\frac {3}{4}-\frac {1}{4+2d_n}).$ So if $d_n>0$ then $\frac {3}{4}d_n>d_{n+1}>0.$